# Can't load leaflet map onto polymer 3 element

Tags: javascript, polymer, leaflet, leaflet.draw, polymer-3.x

So I'm trying to get my leaflet map to load onto my polymer 3 element, but I have an issue because I need the html div tag for the map to load BEFORE my leaflet javascript, or else it throws an error saying there's no container for it.
I can't figure out a way to do this because I'm importing my javascript in so it's always going to load first. I need polymer to somehow let me load the html tag before rendering the javascript. Here is the code for the polymer element:

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import './shared-styles.js';
import './leaflet/leaflet.js';



class MyView1 extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style include="shared-styles">
        :host {
          display: block;

          padding: 10px;
        }
      </style>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="circle">1</div>
        <h1>View One</h1>
        <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

      </div>
    `;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('my-view1', MyView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[import](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/es6) can also be used asyc. Move your import to [ready](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#element-lifecycle) lifecycle callback this way your dom is definitly ready.

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import './shared-styles.js';

class MyView1 extends PolymerElement {
    static get template() {
        return html`
            <style include="shared-styles">
                :host {
                    display: block;
                    padding: 10px;
                }
            </style>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="circle">1</div>
                <h1>View One</h1>
                <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
            </div>
    `;
  }

  ready(){
      super.ready();
      import('./leaflet/leaflet.js').then((leafletModule) => {
          //leaflet is now imported
      });
  }
}

window.customElements.define('my-view1', MyView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's inside your `leaflet.js`. If it's only a bundle from leaflet the problem is not about loading order because leaflet didn't execute anything until you call their functions. But if it contains your initialize code. I would suggest you to create an init function and call it from outside.

If you initialize the map like:

```
let myMap = L.map('mapId')
```

You will got an `Uncaught Error: Map container not found.` because of if you pass string, leaflet will use `document.getElementById` function to find the container element which will cannot be found because of Shadow DOM. Fortunately leaflet allow you to pass the HTMLElement so you can do like:

```
let myMap = L.map(this.$.map)
```

The final code will be like:

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js'
import { style, map, tileLayer } from './leaflet.js'

const styleElement = document.createElement('dom-module')

styleElement.innerHTML =`
  <template>
    <style>
      ${style}
    </style>
  </template>
`

styleElement.register('shared-styles')

class MyView1 extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style include='shared-styles'></style>
      <div class='card'>
        <div id='map' style='width: 900px; height: 500px'></div>
      </div>
    `
  }

  ready () {
    super.ready()

    let myMap = map(this.$.map, {
      center: [51.505, -0.09],
      zoom: 13
    })

    tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
      id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(myMap)
  }
}

window.customElements.define('my-view1', MyView1)
```

I use [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) to bundle `leaflet.js`, see config [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-e1bqie?file=rollup.config.js).

And working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pkv3jm).

Comment: so it's not the bundle from leaflet, it's my own leaflet file where i'm declaring my map and such. When i use "let myMap = map(this.$.map, ....." I get an error saying "$ is undefined", probably since my leaflet file isn't a polymer file.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use `this.$.map` inside your leftlet file, instead you should wrap your code in a function like `init` and pass the map element when you call like `init(this.$.map)` in ready function.